# Why does my iterator return out of range in python3?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

Who could know why this code returns a list out of range?
The data I'm dealing with has over 20 columns...
Where am I going wrong?

```
import itertools
import csv
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

file2 = csv.reader(open('file2_dumy.csv','r'))
file1 = csv.reader(open('file1_data.csv','r'))
import itertools

list1 = csv.reader(open('file2_dumy.csv','r'))
list2 = csv.reader(open('file1_data.csv','r'))
canv = canvas.Canvas('der.pdf')
for i,x in itertools.zip_longest([a for a in list2][1:], [b for b in list1][1:],fillvalue='null'):
    a = i[0]
    b = i[1]
    c = i[2]
    d = x[0]
    e = x[1]
    f = x[2]
    g = x[3]

    canv.drawString(50,700,a)
    canv.drawString(120,700,b)
    canv.drawString(200,700,c)
    canv.drawString(350,700,d)
    canv.drawString(450,700,e)
    canv.drawString(120,600,g)
    canv.showPage()
canv.save()
```

The error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\PyQt5\Backup\SRMS\iterables question sample.py", line 18, in <module>
    g = x[3]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

file2_dumy.csv

[image: file2_dumy]

[image]

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Can you also update your question with a couple of sample lines from `file2_dumy.csv`?

Comment: `[a for a in list2][1:]` is a bit lengthy for `list2[1:]`.

Comment: @quamrana, edited.

Comment: @JoKing, Lengthy here means?

Comment: @Ptar `[a for a in list2][1:]` is a complicated expression for `list2[1:]`

Comment: @JoKing: Actually since the csv reader is not indexable, some transformation is needed. I've just tried `list(list1)[1:]`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Perhaps there are some blank lines in your files.

Comment: Also its odd that the error is: `string index out of range` because I am expecting `x` to be a list.

Comment: @quamrana see my answer regarding `list2[1:]`. Regarding `string index out of range`: its probably because one CSV is shorter than the other and `zip_longest` fills in 'null'. But what's strange is `'null'[3] == 'l'`, so there should be no `out of range error`

Comment: @Ptar maybe you'll have to post the actual csv

Comment: What I'm seeing is that if I change the fill value to a longer string the error goes away

Comment: @Ptar yes, that's what I suspect. Could it be that you hat a shorter fillvalue when you generated that error?

Comment: Yeah, the fill value was '__' before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran this with no errors (python3.6.10).
    import csv
    import itertools

```
for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(csv.reader(open('foo.csv','r')),csv.reader(open('bar.csv','r')), fillvalue='null'):
    print(i[3], j[3])
```

foo.csv:

```
1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,8,
```

bar.csv:

```
1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,8,
4,4,4,4,
```

output:

```
4 4
8 8
l 4
```

One might discuss if 'null' is an appropriate fillvalue, but there is no error. 
If all lines in the CSV have the at least 4 columns, there should be no problem.

I suspect you generated the error with a different fillvalue, a shorter one. Anyways, you should think about the following:

- can your csv files really be of different length?
- if yes do you really need `zip_longest` because then you have to generate data to fill the smaller one up? Maybe you want to use just `zip`, then the longer dataset is cut.
- If you decide you want to fill up data, you should use e.g. `[0,0,0,0]` instead of `'null'`.